# Xampp swiftmailer fatal error

Tags: php, xampp, swiftmailer, mpdf

I am currently running this out of my xampp local server.

But Swiftmailer keeps running into this problem.

This is the code that I am using:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

echo 'Mail sent <br>';  

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com',465,'ssl')
->setUsername('myemail@gmail.com')
->setPassword('mypassword');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
->setFrom(array('myemail@gmail.com'))
->setTo(array('theiremail@gmail.com'))
->setBody('Hello World.');

$result = $mailer->send($message);
if (!$mailer->send($message,$failures)) {
    echo "Failures:";
    print_r($failures);
} else {
    echo "sent";
}
?>
```

This is the same error message that keeps coming up:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 
>   'Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]' in C:\xampp\htdocs\lulbasaur\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:268 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\lulbasaur\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php(62): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\lulbasaur\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(113): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\lulbasaur\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php(79): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\lulbasaur\sample_pdf.php(19): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\lulbasaur\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 268

I used composer to install this on the server by using the following command:

> composer require swiftmailer/swiftmailer

Is my set up incorrect?

- I disabled 2-step verification on my gmail but didn't solve the issue.
- Tried port 26 instead of 465, no error msg but recipient doesn't get the email.
- I enabled 2-step verification and then also enabled app password and used that to send an email with the code, still no results.
- Enabled php_openssl in the php.ini file

Comment: did you do this as well? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: @ATechGuy Yeah I also did that, didn't seem to solve the problem. :(